# Nested Json data to react table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-functional-component, react-fullstack

I need to parse nested json data to normal json which is coming from an api and need to pass that json data to a react table like below :

Json data :

```
  {
   "value":[
      {
         "id":"d38070fd",
         "name":"webwhatsapp",
         "url":"webwhatsapp.com",
         "project":{
            "id":"89ea5860-8dce",
            "name":"whatsapp",
            "url":"",
             "lastUpdateTime":"2021-01-27T11:30:55.523Z"
         },
         "defaultBranch":"branchname",
         "size":33758407,
         "remoteUrl":"remote",
         
      },
      {
         "id":"b0dd02f7",
         "name":"git",
         "url":"github.com",
         "project":{
            "id":"89ea5860",
            "name":"core",
            "url":"github.com",
           "lastUpdateTime":"2021-01-27T11:30:55.523Z"
         },
         "defaultBranch":"branchname",
         "size":30654059,
         "remoteUrl":"url",
      },
        ]
         },
         count : 90
        }
```

Below is my code  :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import 'react-table/react-table.css'


const App = () => {
   const[data,setData] = useState()
    let api = "api";
    let token = "token";
        
            useEffect(() => {
                axios.get(api, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Basic ${token}`} })
            .then(res => {
              
                console.log(res.data)
                setData(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                
                console.log(err)
            })
                
            },[]);
                     
            const columns = () => {
                return [
                    { Header : id,
                      accessor : id
                    }
                  //other column names
               {
                 ]
              
 
              return <ReactTable
               data={data}
               filterable ={true}
               columns ={columns()}
               defaultPageSize={10}
               className="-striped -highlight"
               
               
               />
    
    
        }
     
export default App;
```

I need to pass that json array to react table i have tried like setData(res.data.value.project.id) but this is not working am unable to see data in console and need to store the array of objects in a state hook and need an access to every element in it and also i need send the data to another component.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: So, `console.log(res.data)` does not show anything correct?

Comment: HI @GiovanniEsposito if i give console.log(res.data) data is showing corerctly

Comment: And by making the same get in postman for example you got the same or in postman you see correct values?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito data is showing correctly now but am unable to pass that data to react table as am not understanding mapping